# unix rm -rf taking >24hours to perform folder deletion from gpfs file system

Tags: linux, bash, unix, file-io

user batches have been running for 3-4 years, solution in bau for the same period, all of sudden since 14/8, we have been seeing extended batch run times , specifically extended (more likely never ending) housekeeping job that performs a very simple find with unix rm -rf. The folders it is deleting can have files in excess of 100,000 on occasions, I have seen a 1.5m but this is nothing new.

the case is with ibm but we are no closer to the source root as yet.

wondering if anyone have any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Can you not log the output of the batch job to a file to check what is going on?

Comment: yes this is all done, it is just sitting on the rm -rf, taking long long time to get read of one folder...

Comment: Better to post this question in Unix stack exchange. https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you done an strace on the process?

Comment: Have you installed a new kernel perhaps? If possible try to time the rm -rf in single user mode.